# javascript getTime() returns greater value for older date compared to new date

Tags: javascript, date

javascript getTime() returns the number of milliseconds form midnight Jan 1, 1970 and the time value in the Date Object. but,

```
  new Date('Wed Sep 16 2105 05:30:00 GMT+0530').getTime()
  // returns 4282502400000
  new Date('Tue Oct 26 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530').getTime()
  // returns 1445817600000
```

Shouldn't the value retuned by the later (Tue Oct 26 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530) be greater. 
I want to find the list dates between a given date (inform of timestamp) and today. I wrote the code below with the assumption that the value returned by getTime() for older dates will always be lesser than newer dates.

```
    var timestamp = new Date('9/15/2105, 12:00:00 AM').getTime();
    var startDate = new Date(timestamp);
    // Date.UTC() to avoid timezone and daylight saving 
    var date = new Date(Date.UTC(startDate.getFullYear(),
                       startDate.getMonth(),
                       startDate.getDate()
                        ));
    var currentDay = new Date();
    var currentDayTimestamp = new Date(Date.UTC(currentDay.getFullYear(),
                                        currentDay.getMonth(),
                                        currentDay.getDate()
                                        )).getTime();
    // day in millisec, 24*60*60*1000 = 86400000
    date = new Date(date.getTime() + 86400000);
    var dates = [];
    console.info(date + ' : ' + date.getTime());
    console.info(new Date(currentDayTimestamp) + ' : ' + currentDayTimestamp);
    while(date.getTime() <= currentDayTimestamp) {
        var dateObj = {
            date: date.getUTCDate(),
            month: date.getUTCMonth() + 1,
            year: date.getUTCFullYear()
        }
        dates.push(dateObj);
        date = new Date(date.getTime() + 86400000);
    }
    console.info(JSON.stringify(dates));

   OUTPUT: 
   Wed Sep 16 2105 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST) : 4282502400000
   Tue Oct 27 2015 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST) : 1445904000000
   []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a typo in your dates. One has the year 2105 which is much larger than 2015.